# Autodesk Forge® Model Derivatives API: translate to svf2 error 406 "SVF2 is not supported for this design."

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Once a file is selected, we want to translate it to svf2 format, using the forge-apis package.
Here the code for the translate method:

```
      const derivativesApi = new DerivativesApi()
      this.urn = Buffer.from(this.itemToRender.id).toString('base64')

      const job: JobPayload = {
        input: {
          urn: this.urn
        },
        output: {
          formats: [
            {
              type: 'svf2',
              views: ['2d', '3d']
            }
          ]
        }
      }

      const translation = await derivativesApi.translate(
        job,
        {},
        autodeskClientTwo(),
        await autodeskClientTwo().authenticate()
      )
```

Obtaining error '406' debt to bad request.

[406: "SVF2 is not supported for this design."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjo0p.png)

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the file type of the input model?

Comment: For now, models are BIM-360 browsed uploaded rvt files. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**SVF2** translation is currently only supported for files in **OSS buckets**. So you would have to move the file into your own **OSS bucket** first and then kick off the translation for it.

I cannot tell you at the moment when **SVF2** translation will be available for files on **BIM 360 Docs**